# Hashicorp Packer: vsphere-iso builder deploy multiple disks?

Tags: packer, vsphere

I'm trying to get Hashicorp's Packer (1.5.5) to deploy multiple disks for a specialized (USGCB compliant) template and I need it to have four separate disks. I'm using the `vsphere-iso` builder. The "`disk_size`" parameter deploys the root drive fine.  I found the 'storage' parameter which I *think* is used to deploy the other disks...

`storage ([]DiskConfig) - A collection of one or more disks to be provisioned along with the VM`

But I can't seem to figure out the format that the data needs to be in - in the json file.  I tried...

```
"storage": [
   {
   "storage[1]": "20673",
   "storage[2]": "16384",
   "storage[3]": "4096"
   }
 ]
```

and

```
"storage": [
   {
   "20673",
   "16384",
   "4096"
   }
 ]
```

but none of those worked.

Comment: I checked and there does not seem to be any examples or clarification on what the `DiskConfig` object element of that array should have for syntax. You probably should raise an issue on the Github tracker for a documentation update.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do something similar and what I'm getting is `Failed to initialize build 'vsphere-iso': error initializing builder 'vsphere-iso': Incompatible API version with plugin. Plugin version: 4, Ours: 5`. I'm using Packer 1.5.6. I need to downgrade to 1.4.x to be able to use the Packer plugin. How did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

the storage section contains just the additional disks
you need the following

"disk_controller_type": "pvscsi",

"disk_size": "20673",
"disk_thin_provisioned": true,

"storage": [
  {
    "disk_size": "16384",
    "disk_thin_provisioned": true
  },
  {
    "disk_size": "4096",
    "disk_thin_provisioned": true
  }
],